# How swift closure captures Int?

Tags: swift, closures

Wondering how swift closure capture works? Like `i` value got captured, thought `j` value will also be captured, but it is not. Can someone explain how this `i` and `j` get captured by swift closure?

```
var statements = [()->()]()

var j = 10
for i in 1...10 {
    statements.append {
        print(i)
        print(j)
    }
}

statements[2]() //prints 3 and 10

j = 20

statements[5]() //prints 6 and 20, I was expecting 6 and 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure in question is capturing the reference to variable `j` and it will use any new value assigned to `j`. If you don't want to use the updated value then you have to use the below syntax where closure will capture the value(copy of variable `j`) instead of reference and it will not change.

```
var j = 10
for i in 1...10 {
    statements.append { [j] in
        print(i)
        print(j)
    }
}
```

---

Examples on my comment regarding scope of variable `i` & `j`.

If we make `i` as variable and change the value before invoking the closure, it will change its captured value because closure has captured the reference of variable `i` as below,

```
var j = 10
for var i in 1...10 {
    statements.append { [j] in
        print(i)
        print(j)
    }
    if i == 1 {
        i = 9999
        statements[0]()
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
9999
10
```

But if we capture the value of `i` & `j` as below then nothing will change inside the closure once it captures the values.

```
var j = 10
for var i in 1...10 {
    statements.append { [i, j] in
        print(i)
        print(j)
    }
    if i == 1 {
        i = 9999
        statements[0]()
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1
10
```

Comment: How that `i` is differs from `j` in my question? I checked the address of `i`, it seems same address in each iteration of the loop. So, why it takes value for `i`, but reference for `j`?

Comment: Also can you share some link that explains the usage of `[j] in`?

Comment: @Saran, scope of `i` is limited to each iteration of loop so same memory is available for next iteration and new value will be assigned hence captured value is different for each iteration. While `j` has a global scope and closure will act as per the usage.

Comment: You can check [Capturing Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) section in this documentation for some detail on scope.